# Spring MVC + Thymeleaf: Why is the view returning a new object to controller instead of the original one?

Tags: spring, mongodb, thymeleaf

When I'm updating an object, I send it to the view as a model attribute. But when the view returns it, it comes without the _id (a new object). MongoDB proceeds to create a new object instead of updating an existing one. To avoid this I'm including the id of the object as a hidden input in the view, but that doesn't feel right. Is there another way of achieving this, a more "professional" way?

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("users")
public class UserController {
    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @GetMapping(value = "/save")
    public String saveUserForm(@RequestParam("id") String id, Model model)
    {           
        User user = userRepository.findById(id).get();
        model.addAttribute("user", user);
        return "saveUser";
    }
    @PostMapping(value = "/save") 
    public String saveUser(@ModelAttribute("user") User user) 
    {
        userRepository.save(user);
        return "redirect:/users";
    }
}

**********************saveUser.html***************************
...
<form th:method="POST" th:modelAttribute="user" th:action="@{/users/save}" th:id="saveUserForm">
    <input type="hidden" name ="userId" th:value="${user.userId}"/>
    <label for="name">Name: </label>
    <input type="text" name="name"  th:value="${user.name}"/>
    <br /> 
    <label for="creationDate">Creation: </label>
    <input type="date" name="creationDate"  th:field="${user.creationDate}"/>
    <br /> 
    <input type="submit" value="Update" />
</form>
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `@SessionAttributes("user")` on your controller for this.  It will temporarily store the `user` object on the session during this controller so you don't have to include hidden attributes.

Comment: I thought of that, but seemed a bit too much. I mean, isn't @SessionAttributes supposed to be used when you need to persist a variable through various views? I thought, that maybe, a more narrow solution existed. But I'll use SessionAttributes anyway, thanks for the reply.

Comment: SessionAttributes are different than putting the object on with session.setAttribute (which lasts the entire session). SessionAttributes apply to the specific controller only -- `attributes which are supposed to be stored in the session temporarily`.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. Will use it.